# AJAX success function not executing in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I wrote the following script using jquery and ajax in the wordpress. Data inserted successfully in the database. But **success:function(data)** that is not work perfectly. my submit form doesn't clear and success message doesn't display. Few days ago that was working perfectly.What is happend i cant recognize it. Could any help me to check the script.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#addestimate', function () { 

        var estmateno = document.getElementById('estmateno').value;
        var itr_customer = document.getElementById('itr_customer').value;
        var cemail = document.getElementById('cemail').value;
        var caddress = document.getElementById('caddress').value;
        var bdate = document.getElementById('bdate').value;
        var epdate = document.getElementById('epdate').value;

        var sub_total = document.getElementById('sub_total').value;
        var itr_est_message = document.getElementById('itr_est_message').value;
        var itr_state_message = document.getElementById('itr_state_message').value;   

        var detaillist = [];

        jQuery('.griditems').each(function () {

          var iindex = jQuery(this).attr('itemindex');
          var product = jQuery("#product"+iindex).val();
          var itr_customer = jQuery("#itr_customer").val();
          var estmateno = jQuery("#estmateno").val();
          var description = jQuery("#description"+iindex).val();
          var qty = jQuery("#qty"+iindex).val();
          var price = jQuery("#price"+iindex).val();
          var total = jQuery("#total"+iindex).val();

          detaillist.push({
            'product': product,
            'itr_customer' : itr_customer,
            'estmateno'  : estmateno,
            'description': description,
            'qty'  : qty,
            'price' : price,
            'total' : total,

          });
        });

      var dlist = detaillist;

      if (estmateno == '' || itr_customer == '' || cemail == '' || bdate == '' || epdate == '' ) 
       { 
         jQuery('#error_message').text('*All above Fields are Required');

      }else { 
      console.log('estime');
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajax_url,
          type:"POST",
          cache: true,
          dataType:"json",
          data: {

            'action':'new_db_estimate_info', 
            "dlist": dlist, 
            'estmateno' : estmateno,
            'itr_customer' : itr_customer,
            'cemail' : cemail,
            'caddress' : caddress,
            'bdate' : bdate,
            'epdate' : epdate,
            'sub_total' : sub_total,
            'itr_est_message' : itr_est_message,
            'itr_state_message' : itr_state_message
          },

          beforeSend:function(){
           jQuery('#error_message').text('');
           jQuery(".entry-content #processingdiv").css({'visibility':'visible'});
          },
          
          success:function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log('Rashed khan');
              itr_customer_list_show_invoice();
              total_estimate_amount();
              itr_estimate_list_show();
              console.log('Itr');
              jQuery("body .emessage").html('Estimate Done successfully');
              jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
                 
              if(data=='Estimate Done successfully'){
               jQuery('.emessage').text(data.emessage);   
               jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
               //jQuery('form')[0].reset();

             }else{
              jQuery('#survey_error_message').text(data);
              jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
            }
          },

        complete: function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery("#processingdiv").css({'visibility':'hidden'});
        }, 6000);
      },
        error: function(errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Hey man, the first thing that i noticed was that variable 'ajax_url' that you have passed in your ajax call's url, i don't see any definition of it inside the script. I would start with that. But since u mentioned that the data is successfully being saved in the database, its abit suspicious. Does it throw any errors instead?